# Flying in the EU, can I transit in Istanbul airport without a passport?

Tags: turkey, eu-citizens

I was going to book tickets from Bucharest to Malta, but there is a stop in Istanbul, Turkey. Can I take this flight with just a Romanian ID card?

The Turkish airlines transit information page suggest I can. http://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/travel-information/baggage/transit-transfer-passenger-procedures

> International transfer passengers flight routes issued on single
>   ticket continuing to a foreign destination with Turkish Airlines*
>
> - Passengers disembark with only their cabin baggage and proceed
>     directly to the boarding gates without any flight or passport
>     procedures.

The layover time is around 4 hours.

I'd like to know if any of you tried this and if you encountered any troubles?

Comment: Related but no conclusive answer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293974-i368-k8873724-Transit_Istanbul_with_EU_ID_card_and_no_passport-Istanbul.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also asked the Turkish airlines sales office and received the reply below:

> Puteti calatori doar cu cartea de identitate cu conditia sa nu iesiti
>   din zona de tranzit.
>
> Buh Tk Office

Translation:

> You can travel with just the identity card on the condition that you
>   don't exit the transit zone.

Update following @phoog's suggestion. I also asked the Turkish embassy in Romania and received a similar answer:

> Daca veti tranzita Turcia fara a parasi aria aeroportului nu aveti
>   nevoie de paşaport. Daca veti parasi aria aeroportului aveti nevoie de
>   paşaport valabil minim 6 luni.

Translation:

> You don't need a passport if you'll transit in Turkey without leaving the airport. To leave the airport you need a passport valid for a minimum of 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

Turkey is not part of the EU, so I would imagine the check-in counter at Bucharest will ask for your passport - as it is the valid travel document.

Comment: Citizens of some countries (most of which are in the EU) can enter Turkey with an ID card in lieu of a passport.  These people can presumably also transit in Turkey with their ID cards.  Romania is not on the list, however.  See http://www.mfa.gov.tr/countries-whose-citizens-are-allowed-to-enter-turkey-with-their-national-id_s.en.mfa.

Answer (score -1):

You will (surely?) need a passport when boarding your plane in Bucharest (and getting thru security);

The cited quote only means that if a passenger is in transit he should not go thru passport check again. (he should have had his passport checked already)

because of the latest events in Istanbul it might have changed, and there might be more security checks, even for passengers in transit.

Comment: I received a reply from turkish airlines' sales office telling me I can; that said they won't be the ones at the security/border check...

Comment: ok, but what about security at both Bucharest and Malta's airports ?

Comment: You can travel within the EU with just the ID card and the airports accept it.

Comment: @csiz You won't have a border check in Istanbul (unless you try to leave the transit zone).  You should consider editing your question to remove the update, and posting that information as an answer instead.  Then you can accept it.

Comment: @phoog I'm not entirely confident in their answer since they're not the ones that have the final say. That said I booked the tickets, but I'll also try to renew my passport until I leave.